# Express server running as Docker image container only serving some html pages

Tags: node.js, docker, express

**Problem**

Node/express Docker image running locally serving some html pages and not others

**Explanation**

I have a Node/Express application as a Docker image being run locally as a Docker container. This is app is serving html pages the usual way one would when using Express. However it seems I can access only some of these pages and not others despite the express routes being almost identical

```
server.js

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    user: req.user
  });
});

app.get('/signup/terms', function (req, res, ) {
  res.render('signup/terms', {
    user: req.user
  })
})

app.get('/signup/map', function (req, res, ) {
  res.render('signup/map', {
    user: req.user
  })
})
```

I can access index and /signup/terms no problem, all the html, css and images load, but when i visit /signup/map I get a 500 status code

`GET /signup/map 500 5.980 ms - 47`

**Things I've tried:**

I've tried looking into the docker container file directory using:

`docker exec -it <container> sh`

to check all the files are there and they are and the image is up to date.

Here's the docker config i used to build the image:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

# DEV RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

I've also tried rebuilding the image with the --no-cache option but to no avail.

I thought it might be a directory issue but the fact that some pages are serving and some are not is perplexing...

Does any one know whats happening here?

**Update:** Turns out it was a problem with the ejs templating. I had pages that had un-passed variables causing the server to throw the 500 status.

Comment: I guess that there are some error messages when you request the api. You can open log files of the container by docker logs <your-container>

Comment: Don't seem to be getting an extra info here, the logs from the express server which are only telling me the status codes. 200 for /signup/terms and 500 for /signup/map